# wordpress site ignoring sub directory when htaccess present

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, directory, subdirectory

To begin I did not setup the website I am currently working on, and I am not very familiar with the wordpress setups. I have been called in on their site to add an admin section to this site which uses a Wordpress configuration. If I add a sub-directory, I can access the sub-dir via web just fine. The problem comes when I add a .htaccess to that subdirectory for Auth purposes. When I do this, and try to access the sub-directory, it errors to a 'Page Not Found'.

Can someone please help? I assume it is something with the Wordpress .htaccess file provided below:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

---

**UPDATE**

When the .htaccess in the sub directory is blank, I can access the sub-directory via web just fine.
.htaccess (when filled out) in sub directory is below:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Sphere"
AuthUserFile "/path/to/htpasswd"
require valid-user
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tested a setup based off of your question. Here's an example of the hierarchy from what I could gather in your post:

```
public_html/ (all WP install files here)
public_html/admin/ (here I created a new folder similar to your question)
public_html/admin/index.php (test file - just echos a line of text)
public_html/admin/.htaccess (currently blank)
```

So my .htaccess within the new subdir that's spawned off of the WP root is blank. I'm not sure what kind of auth things would/should be in there. If I access "website/admin/" - the test line echos just fine. I don't see any 404s.

Could you maybe provide a little more detail so I can try to better replicate the issue you're seeing?

Comment: thank you for your response. Unfortunately it just did the same thing again. I just setup a new directory, named sphere, and when I did it with no htaccess it worked fine when going to the directory www.site.com/sphere. But, when the htaccess was added, it errored same again. here is htaccess in the sub-dir: `AuthType Basic
AuthName "Sphere"
AuthUserFile "my_htpasswd/path"
require valid-user`

Comment: btw your answer was helpful in identifying that it was something specifically in the sub-dir htaccess file that was throwing it off, not the presence of the .htaccess file itself. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution for my problem elsewhere. Editing the root .htaccess (for wordpress) to match the one below should fix anyone who also encounters this issue:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/NameOf_Directory_ToAllow/(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/NameOf_AdditionalDirectory_ToAllow/(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```